# Why doesn't late static binding work with variables in PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, variables, inheritance, static, late-static-binding

Let's start off with some code:

```
class Super {

    protected static $color;

    public static function setColor($color){
        self::$color = $color;
    }

    public static function getColor() {
        return self::$color;
    }

}

class ChildA extends Super { }

class ChildB extends Super { }

ChildA::setColor('red');
ChildB::setColor('green');

echo ChildA::getColor();
echo ChildB::getColor();
```

Now, late static binding in PHP 5.3 using the *static* keyword works great with static methods, so I assumed it would do the same magic on static variables. Well, seems it doesn't. The example above does not print out "red" and then "green" as I first expected, but "green" and "green". Why doesn't this work on variables when it works on methods? Is there any other way to achieve the effect I expected?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Late static binding will only work for new definitions of variables / methods. Thus, in your example, the `$color` property of `Super` will always be modified instead of `ChildA` or `ChildB`. To make use of late static binding, you need to use the `static` keyword instead of `self`. Furthermore, you need to redefine the `$color` property of your `ChildA` and `ChildB` classes:

```
class Super {

    protected static $color;

    public static function setColor($color){
        // static instead of self
        static::$color = $color;
    }

    public static function getColor() {
        // static instead of self
        return static::$color;
    }

}

class ChildA extends Super {
    protected static $color;
}
class ChildB extends Super {
    protected static $color;
}

ChildA::setColor('red');
ChildB::setColor('green');

echo Super::getColor(); // prints nothing (NULL = ''), expected
echo ChildA::getColor();// prints red
echo ChildB::getColor();// prints green
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Lekensteyn. That does sort of ruin some of the comfort of inheritance a little bit, but I'll manage :)

Comment: Thanks this really helped. I fell into the same trap; I was missing redefining the variable in the child classes! Do you have any literature on this as I seemed to miss this vital piece in the PHP docs.